# How to load image from the server rather than the cache?

Tags: html, image, browser-cache

I have some images in my website that change from time to time.

The problem is that the browser loads the old images from the cache.

How can I tell to browser to always load the images from the server instead of the cache?

Comment: That depends. You can solve it on the client by adding for instance a timestamp to the image url with clientscript (image.jpg?timestamp=14565545) or configure your server to add cache headers. What kind of webserver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is using kind of a versioning on the src="img.jpg" with using such

```
  <img src="img.jpg?12354636512">
```

12354636512 this number should be different allways so you can use the current time for example to add such unique versions to your image urls. Browser will think that this is different then what it downloaded to temp already and will request it again.

Answer (score 2):

you can change the src of the image to include a useless random number:

> EDIT: use a current timestamp instead to ensure it's never the same,
>   but basically do the same thing.

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('yourimageclassname');

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  var num = Math.random();
  imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src + '?' + num;
}

document.getElementById('result').value = imgs[0].src;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="result" style="width:100%;" />

<img class="yourimageclassname" src="http://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
```

Comment: But with a useless random number there *is* a tiny chance you hit the same number again, there is a cache hit and your image isn't reloaded. I think current timestamp is better for this purpose.

Comment: @NielsV: Using the actual last modified timestamp of the image file would be even better (assuming a server-side technique that can read that value from the file system can be used) – otherwise caching will be _completely_ disabled, so the browser would have to load the image over and over again on every new page request, even if it has _not_ changed.

Comment: @CBroe but that was in the original question (load the image from the server every time the page loads)

Comment: @NielsV: What someone _asks_ for might not always be what they _actually_ want or need ;-) And since it also said, that the images change “from time to time”, I though this was a point worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the web server you are using, nginx, apache2, node...

In the config of this web server just set a control for images(png, jpg).
Nginx:

```
location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
        expires 1d;
    }
```

A little work around is to append to the image everytime a new a string(based on time), so the browser will see the image as a new one: `<img src="picture.jpg?20130910043254">`